# WCF Service - Load Testing

Tags: wcf

I have my WCF service hosted as Windows Service and all the exposed methods are defined as OneWay=true.

Now, I want to test this service to see how service will respond to 100s of clients in real time scenario.

Can anyone please guide what steps I can take to achieve above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [WCFStorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/) or [WCF Load Test.](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If the services are exposed via HTTP, than you can used Fiddler and StressStimulus plugin.
Works well, allows to provide some load scenarios and generates reports.

There is a limited free version.
http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com/